# How to create a vector of unique pointers of a class

Tags: c++, c++14

I am looking at a code which uses new and delete to create pointers for classes and I am trying to update the code to use unique pointers. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Algorithm
{
    private:
    public:
        virtual void runn_algo() = 0;
        virtual ~Algorithm() {};
};

class Algo1 : public Algorithm
{
        void runn_algo()
        {
                std::cout << "running Algo1" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Algo2 : public Algorithm
{
        void runn_algo()
        {
                std::cout << "running Algo2" << std::endl;
        }
};

class runner
{
    public:
        void runn_algo(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> upa)
        {
                upa->runn_algo();
        }
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Algorithm>> algos;

        algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
        algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
        algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo2>());

        runner run;

        for (auto i = 0u; i < algos.size(); ++i)
        {
                run.runn_algo(algos[i]);
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<Algorithm>'
                run.runn_algo(algos[i]);
```

I am not sure why this is happening. the code with raw pointers is working fine

```
class runner
{
    public:
        void runn_algo(Algorithm* upa)
        {
                upa->runn_algo();
        }
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<Algorithm*> algos;

        algos.push_back(new Algo1());
        algos.push_back(new Algo1());
        algos.push_back(new Algo2());

        runner run;

        for (auto i = 0u; i < algos.size(); ++i)
        {
                run.runn_algo(algos[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message indicates, `unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor and so cannot be passed by value to a function. You can change the signature to accept a `const std::unique_ptr<Algorithm>&` reference instead:

```
class runner
{
public:
    void runn_algo(const std::unique_ptr<Algorithm>& upa)
    {
        upa->runn_algo();
    }
};
```

Which produces the output

```
running Algo1
running Algo1
running Algo2
```

As expected.

Alternatively, write `runner::runn_algo` in such a way that it doesn't care about how the `Algorithm` is stored:

```
class runner
{
public:
    void runn_algo(Algorithm& algo)
    {
        algo.runn_algo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Algorithm>> algos;

    algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
    algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
    algos.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Algo2>());

    runner run;

    for (auto i = 0u; i < algos.size(); ++i)
    {
        run.runn_algo(*algos[i]); // Dereference operator on algos[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: But then, why not just pass a reference to the object, via `runn_algo(*upa)`? If the function doesn't care that it happens to be allocated by a `unique_ptr`, it shouldn't be burdened by that knowledge in its signature. And it's hard to think why any function would need a `const unique_ptr&`, since all it can do with that is dereference and check the address, which can be done with a normal `const&` anyway.

Comment: Good point, although isn't `*upa.get()` a little verbose when you could just say `*upa`?

Comment: Yeah, I momentarily forgot about that; I blame `std::reference_wrapper`!

Comment: Or even `const Algorithm&` and dereference pointer. Makes for cleaner interface in my mind. Gluing runner to unique pointers seems weird.

Comment: Not `const Algorithm&` because `Algorithm::runn_algo` isn't a `const` member function, presumably for good reason.

Comment: Fair enough, missed this. Just `Algorithm&` than.

Comment: You could also choose a normal pointer, `Algorithm*`

Comment: You could have `runner::runn_algo` take an `Algorithm*` pointer and the calling code would be `algos[i].get()`, yes. Wouldn't really be much different from the `Algorithm&` version unless you wanted to write the ability to handle `nullptr` in some fashion.

Answer (score 2):

First your `emplace_back` should actually be a `push_back` since you are using `make_unique`

```
algos.push_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
algos.push_back(std::make_unique<Algo1>());
algos.push_back(std::make_unique<Algo2>());
```

Second you should use `virtual` and `override` to make your methods polymorphic

```
virtual void runn_algo();  // base
void runn_algo() override; // derived
```

Third you should probably pass the argument as a raw (non-owning) pointer to your `runner`, because if you try to pass `unique_ptr` by value, it will try to copy, which is not allowed by a `unique_ptr`

```
void runn_algo(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> alg);  // nope, cannot copy
void runn_algo(Algorithm* alg);                  // ok, non-owning

for (auto i = 0u; i < algos.size(); ++i)
{
    run.runn_algo(algos[i].get());               // access underlying pointer
}
```

Though in this case, I don't really see the point of the `runner` as you can just use the polymorphism here

```
for (auto& alg : algos)
{
    alg->run_algo();  // will be polymorphic
}
```

Comment: I think I future, I might extend the runner class. Thanks!

Comment: `push_back` may be clearer than `emplace_back`, but it doesn't really end up affecting the functionality of the program. `Algorithm::runn_algo` is _already_ `virtual`, so while it might be nice for clarity to give `Algo1::runn_algo` the `override` or `final` specifier, it doesn't address the problem. Only the point about the non-copyability of `std::unique_ptr` will help with the question.

Comment: First point is nitty. `push_back` is not different from `emplace_back` in this context. Second point misses important piece - OP already has the function as `virtual`, but `override` is quite important and it seemed to be glossed over here. Third point is relevant. Overall score: 1/3.

Comment: Any particular reason why `push_back` was preferred by Cory? My googling suggested the `emplace_back` should be used as we can only move `unique_ptr`s

Comment: @Morpheus you can use `push_back`, it will call move constructor. In the example provided, it makes no difference which version is used. The behavior would be completely identical.

Comment: `emplace_back` is semantically slightly redundant. It signifies calling the constructor of the container's class with the arguments provided, but you already have to do that when you invoke `make_unique`. But as pointed out it doesn't really affect the program's functionality in this case.